# Sudden Error with Python Requests and MailJet API

Tags: python, mailjet

I have been using the Python MailJet API successfully for some time. However, I am now getting an error from that script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/sbin/mailjet.py", line 6, in 
>   from mailjet_rest import Client
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailjet_rest/**init**.py", line 4, in 
>   from .client import Client
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailjet_rest/client.py", line 11, in  requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'

I'm not sure what the error means but it is coming from the MailJet library when I do the import. The Requests library is installed so that can't be the problem. I know Python 2.7 is now deprecated but that is the version on which CentOS 7 depends. How do I go about debugging this since I do not have the MailJet source? TIA.

Comment: Could you upload the content of `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mailjet_rest/client.py` in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or anything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not pick up on that part of the traceback. I am looking at this code now but it is MailJet code not mine. I would hate to make any changes. In any case I need some time to look at it. Particularly the line in question.    'requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()'

Comment: I'm importing it just fine. I don't know how to reproduce your issue

Comment: Were any of the packages you're using changed somehow?